# Compile Cplex in java in Linux 2

Tags: java, linux, cplex

I'm trying to run a file.java and file.class for which I need to use a library of Cplex (optimization problem) using

```
$ javac -cp /home/apps/cplex/12.6.1/cplex/lib/cplex.jar file.java
$ java -cp /home/apps/cplex/12.6.1/cplex/lib/cplex.jar:. file
```

which was recommended when I asked in [Compile Cplex in Java in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543018/compile-cplex-in-java-in-linux) . I finally ended the correction of my file (thing that worked in windows didn't in Linux) and the first line worked, but in the second one I got this error...

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no cplex1261 in java.library.path
java.library.path must point to the directory containing the CPLEX shared library
try invoking java with java -Djava.library.path=...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ilog.cplex.Cplex.CPXopenCPLEX([I)J
        at ilog.cplex.Cplex.CPXopenCPLEX(Native Method)
        at ilog.cplex.CplexI.init(CplexI.java:6608)
        at ilog.cplex.CplexI.<init>(CplexI.java:629)
        at ilog.cplex.IloCplex.<init>(IloCplex.java:10194)
        at ilog.cplex.IloCplex.<init>(IloCplex.java:10209)
        at memoria.bosques.problemafull(bosques.java:11395)
        at memoria.bosques.main2(bosques.java:17829)
        at memoria.bosques.main(bosques.java:18014)
```

I tried replacing java -Djava.library.path=/home/apps/cplex/12.6.1/cplex/lib/cplex.jar  instead of -cp /home/apps/cplex/12.6.1/cplex/lib/cplex.jar but didn't work either.
The error occur in the fist time I define something of Cplex(before this was running fine)

```
IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();
```

what can I do to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do exactly what is suggested in the error message. And invoke `java` with `-Djava.library.path` pointing to the locations of the cplex shared module.

Something like this:

```
java -cp /home/apps/cplex/12.6.1/cplex/lib/cplex.jar:. -Djava.library.path=/path/to/libcplex121.so file
```

Comment: i found a libcplex.a  but i don't see anywhere  .so  , do i have to use libcplex121.so or libcplex121.a  ??

Comment: If you installed and configured Cplex correctly you must have `libcplex.so` file. `-Djava.library.path` must point to the directory containing this file. Install and configure Cplex correctly.

Comment: i found one in the opl folder  and used  java  -cp /home/apps/cplex/12.6.1/cplex/lib/cplex.jar:. -Djava.library.path=/home/apps/cplex/12.6.1/opl/bin/x86-64_linux/libcplex1261.so   memoria/bosques  but didn't work either... :/

Comment: -Djava.library.path=/home/apps/cplex/12.6.1/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux/libcplex1261.so    is the other one... didn't work :(

Comment: Try just -Djava.library.path=/home/apps/cplex/12.6.1/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux

Comment: I got this:
-bash: -Djava.library.path=/home/apps/cplex/12.6.1/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux/libcplex1261.so: No such file or directory ...but if i do the  ls of the directory it clearly appears the file  in the terminal

Comment: in the end the error said to put the path to the directory (and not to the file) i changed that and worked  ....thanks for your help!